# Display Image from SQL Server image datatype in vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Please help. I'm trying to display images to the program I made.. but I did not have to insert it. Another system is inserting the picture, so I'm not sure how they insert it. I just can access the SQL Server data. So now I try to retrieve the image and display it in DatagridView, but I always get this error:

Image is error

[image]

Error

[image]

This is what the database look like.. datatype : image

[image]

And this is my code. Please help me.

```
 Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(" select * from iUserPicture ", Connection)

    cmd.Connection = Connection
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim table As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(table)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    DataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 100

    Dim imgc As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
    imgc = DataGridView1.Columns(1)
    imgc.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch
```

Comment: The `DataGridView` simply try to create an `Image` object from the provided `Byte` array via a `MemoryStream`.  If the data provided doesn't represent a valid `Image` object then it can't do so.  We can't magically tell you what the data does represent because we don't know anything about it.  You need to go to whoever created the data in the first place and ask them how they created it so that you can reverse that process.

Comment: actually that is software that come with fingerprint device. how can i find who creat it.

Comment: Maybe you should read the documentation for the hardware and/or the software that comes with it.  The data is likely to represent a hash or something like that, not an image at all.  You need to put some thought into it and do some research though.  We shouldn't have to tell you to go to the hardware/software provider first.  Sites like this should be your last resort, not your first port of call.